# What is the meaning of "you are" in the sentences

Tags: ellipsis

I don't understand the meaning of "you are" in this sentence:

> I'm not crying you are.

Found in a [meme on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/wholesomememes/comments/c6fub1/im_not_crying_you_are/).

Answer (score 2):

Not one sentence but two sentences. It should perhaps be written

> I'm not crying. You are.

The second sentence omits the word "crying", it means "You are crying"

Comment: True that. Many memes are notoriously poorly punctuated.

Comment: Given it's very short length, it would be generally accepted as a single-sentence comma splice—if a comma were added.